# How to change body background image on menu item hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a menu and I need to change the body background to different image on every menu item. Also, it would be nice if it would fade or bounce or do something nice and clean while changing.

So far I have this code:

```
    var $body = $('body');
    $('li:first-child').hover(function(){
        $body.css('background-image', 'url("img/dd.jpg")');
    }, function() {
        $body.css('background-image', '')
    })
```

The html is

```
<div id="main-menu-container">
    <ul>
       <li><a><span>One</span></a></li>

       <li><a><span>Two</span></a></li>

       <li><a><span>Three</span></a></li>      
    </ul>
</div>
```

How do I continue and add the animation?

Comment: Your code above should be working fine. Do you got any errors or what is the problem? https://jsfiddle.net/crjzsL1z/

Comment: @eisbehr I think his question is how to add the fading or bouncing animation, he knows his code is working.

Comment: The question is, how do I add a second element, for example #menu-item-18 to the code, so that it would still work and how to I add the animation fade for example or something else. I would like to see the background change in some kind of a smooth beautiful or cool way.

Comment: You should show us your menu html too, then we can look for the best way to add more listeners. @monss

Comment: added html @eisbehr

Comment: I can't see the `#menu-item-16` in your code? Where would they be?

Comment: So yeah, I removed the #menu-item-16. It is just a list with <li> tags. I guess when there is no classes or ID-s the code should be a loop? @eisbehr

Answer (score 2):

You can just select the items where you want to change the background.

```js
var $body = $('body');
$('#main-menu-container li a').hover(function(){
    $body.css('background', 'red');
}, function() {
    $body.css('background', '')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-menu-container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>One</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Two</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Three</span></a></li>      
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you want a different background you need to store them somehow. Maybe as `data` attribute on the menu, or create a object, storing the images, or something.

```js
var $body = $('body');
var colors = ['#f00', '#f0f', '#0f0'];

$('#main-menu-container li a').hover(function(){
    $body.css('background', colors[$(this).parent().index()]);
}, function() {
    $body.css('background', '')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-menu-container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>One</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Two</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Three</span></a></li>      
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: YES!! This last one is exactly what I am looking for! Now I only need the backgrounds to change smoother. @eisbehr

Comment: Are you using only colors, or images? Images are not that easy here. There you have to use tricks. @monss

Comment: images yes @eisbehr

Answer (score 0):

Try to add all the images to the page with `z-index:-1` and `position:fixed`. Then just animate opacities of those images. Here's HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="myscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class = "images-container">
        <img src="img1.jpg">
        <img src="img2.jpg">
        <img src="img3.jpg">
        <img src="img0.jpg">
    </div>
    <ul id = "main-menu-container">
        <li><a><span>One</span></a></li>
       <li><a><span>Two</span></a></li>
       <li><a><span>Three</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div.images-container img{
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    width:1600px;
    height: 900px;
}

ul#main-menu-container{
    position: relative;
    top:50px;
}

ul#main-menu-container li{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #ed2389;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-width: 1px;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

ul#main-menu-container li:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color: #ed2389;
    border-color: #ed2389;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.images-container img").fadeOut(0);
    $("div.images-container img").last().fadeIn(0);
    $("#main-menu-container").hover(function(){
        $("div.images-container img").last().fadeToggle(500);
    });
    $("#main-menu-container li").hover(function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        var $menu = $("#main-menu-container li");
        var index = $menu.index($target);
        var $images = $("div.images-container img");
        $images.eq(index).fadeToggle(500);
    });
});
```

Here I used the order of the images to choose what image is going to be displayed. For more control you can use ids and classes. 
Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eoppskvL/

P.S. I don't own any of the images in the fiddle in case I need to say that.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so I figured it out. Thank you for your help people!

The html

```
<div id="main-menu-container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Two</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Three</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
body {
    background: url("../img/back.png");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transition: background ease-in 1s;
    -moz-transition: background ease-in 1s;
    -o-transition: background ease-in 1s;
    transition: background ease-in 1s;
}

.background-0 {
background: url("../img/dd.jpg");
}
.background-1 {
background: url("../img/dd.jpg");
}
.background-2 {
    background: url("../img/dd.jpg");
}
```

The script

```
var list_elements = $('ul li');
var current_index = null;
list_elements.on('mouseenter', function() {
    current_index = list_elements.index(this);
    $('body').addClass('background-' + current_index);

}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    $('body').removeClass('background-' + current_index);
    current_index = null;
});
```

Comment: Dear friend, you would be trying to implement something similar to this page? https://www.verb.studio/case-studies/
Or coincidence you are responsible for it?

Comment: something similar yes @user1906245

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you cannot animate the background-image of an element. You could use [this trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/) to add a transparent background and animate the opacity of the `:after` pseudo-element.